# xBR algorithm clarification

Tags: algorithm, shader

Does anyone here have experience with the xBR algorithm and could care to explain one thing?

I am reading the explanation of the algorithm on this forum [thread](http://helmet.kafuka.org/byuubackup/viewtopic.php@f=10&t=2248.html)

In the thread it is said: "For that reason, from now on, all algorithm terms will be related to the down-right edge. You'll have to apply the same rules to the other three edges by symmetry.". I interpret it as I have to weigh the distance on all four edges, i.e top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right. But in all the implementations I have seen of the shader the weight distance is only checked for the bottom-right corner and not the others? It seems like I am missing something.

Example shader [here](https://github.com/libretro/common-shaders/blob/master/xbr/shaders/xbr-lv2.cg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. It was some nice matrix multiplication and saving the weighted distances from all directions in a bool4, doing all the calculations simultaneously